# Performance tips for finding unique permutation

Tags: php, arrays, performance, sorting

**TLDR:**
[how to find multidimensional array permutation in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47070600/how-to-find-multidimensional-array-permutation-in-php) and how to optimize for bigger arrays?

This is continuation of this question:
[how to find multidimensional array permutation in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47070600/how-to-find-multidimensional-array-permutation-in-php)

we have script for sorting array, idea is to find unique permutation of array, rules to find this permutation are:

> 1. Input array contains set of arrays.
> 2. Each inner array contains unique elements.
> 3. Each inner array may have different length and different values.
> 4. Output array must contain exact same values.
> 5. Output inner array must have unique values on same key.
> 6. If there is no solution, wildcard  `ie.: null` are allowed.
> 7. Wildcards can be duplicated on same key.
> 8. Solution should have as few wildcards as possible.
> 9. Algorithm should be able to handle array up to **30x30** in less than 180 s.

i have this solution so far:

```
function matrix_is_solved(array $matrix) {
    foreach (array_keys(current($matrix)) as $offset) {
        $column = array_filter($raw = array_column($matrix, $offset));
        if (count($column) != count(array_unique($column))) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function matrix_generate_vectors(array $matrix) {
    $vectors = [];
    $columns = count(current($matrix));
    $gen = function ($depth=0, $combo='') use (&$gen, &$vectors, $columns) {
        if ($depth < $columns)
             for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++)
                $gen($depth + 1, $i . $combo);
        else
            $vectors[] = array_map('intval', str_split($combo));
    };
    $gen();
    return $vectors;
}

function matrix_rotate(array $matrix, array $vector) {
   foreach ($matrix as $row => &$values) {
       array_rotate($values, $vector[$row]);
   }
   return $matrix;
}

function matrix_brute_solve(array $matrix) {
    matrix_make_square($matrix);
    foreach (matrix_generate_vectors($matrix) as $vector) {
        $attempt = matrix_rotate($matrix, $vector);
        if (matrix_is_solved($attempt))
            return matrix_display($attempt);
    }
    echo 'No solution';
}

function array_rotate(array &$array, $offset) {
    foreach (array_slice($array, 0, $offset) as $key => $val) {
        unset($array[$key]);
        $array[$key] = $val;
    }
    $array = array_values($array);
}

function matrix_display(array $matrix = null) {
    echo "[\n";
    foreach ($matrix as $row => $inner) {
        echo "  $row => ['" . implode("', '", $inner) . "']\n";
    }
    echo "]\n";
}

function matrix_make_square(array &$matrix) {
    $pad = count(array_keys($matrix));
    foreach ($matrix as &$row)
        $row = array_pad($row, $pad, '');
}

$tests = [
[ ['X'], ['X'] ],
[ ['X'], ['X'], ['X'] ],
[ [ 'X', '' ], [ '', 'X' ] ],
[ ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['X', 'Y'], ['X']],
[ ['X', 'Y'], ['X', 'Y'], ['X', 'Y'] ]
];
array_map(function ($matrix) {
    matrix_display($matrix);
    echo "solved by:" . PHP_EOL;
    matrix_brute_solve($matrix);
    echo PHP_EOL;
}, $tests);
```

And this works perfectly on small array, but trouble is this iterating over all possibilities of array movements, and for array like 6x6 this is just too much to compute - `O(nn)` in both time *and* space!

Comment: In the earlier question, you mentioned a 30x30 target array. Can you post that - or equivalent - for developing a solution against?

Comment: You need a permutation right? Not all the permutations?

Comment: i need single (first) permutations thats matches all rules, yes

Comment: well, yes but there must be solution to this except quantum computer, people fly to space those days...

Comment: So if I understand the question your trying to generate an array that contains all the possible values in all sub arrays, as outlined in the previously mentioned question?

Comment: I made a small mistake last night, but a small fix was enough to solve it so I undeleted the post and updated it.

Comment: @DorienCragen Are you still looking for a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, i cant sleep I even post fresh question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47469825/finding-unique-permutation-of-2d-array but fell free to answer here

Comment: @Yoshi is not duplicate, I not asking about code, but about algorithm, general solution in any language, or just different aproach, i will put bounty on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite some fiddling, I came up with the following code.

The idea is to identify conflicting elements and swap them to a column where they are no longer a problem. For cases where this is not applicable a random selection is done. The code works recursive and thus there are edge-cases where it takes very long to complete.

An extreme edge-case is an input where all rows consist of exactly the same values.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

final class SwapSolver
{
    /**
     * @param array $input
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function solve(array $input): array
    {
        $input = array_values($input);

        return $this->swapDuplicates($this->prepare($input, $this->getMinRowLength($input)));
    }

    /**
     * @param array $input
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function swapDuplicates(array $input): array
    {
        $unswappable = [];

        foreach ($this->duplicates($input) as $position) {
            list($r, $a) = $position;

            $swapped = false;
            foreach ($this->swapCandidates($input, $r, $a, true) as $b) {
                $input[$r] = $this->swap($input[$r], $a, $b);
                $swapped = true;
                break;
            }

            if (!$swapped) {
                $unswappable[] = $position;
            }
        }

        // still unswappable
        $unswappable = array_values(array_filter($unswappable, function (array $position) use ($input): bool {
            return $this->isDuplicate($input, ...$position);
        }));

        // tie breaker
        if (count($unswappable) > 0) {
            list($r, $a) = $unswappable[mt_rand(0, count($unswappable) - 1)];

            $candidates = [];
            foreach ($this->swapCandidates($input, $r, $a, false) as $b) {
                $candidates[] = $b;
            }

            $input[$r] = $this->swap($input[$r], $a, $candidates[mt_rand(0, count($candidates) - 1)]);

            return $this->swapDuplicates($input);
        }

        return $input;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $input
     *
     * @return \Generator
     */
    private function duplicates(array &$input): \Generator
    {
        foreach ($input as $r => $row) {
            foreach ($row as $c => $value) {
                if ($this->isDuplicate($input, $r, $c)) {
                    yield [$r, $c];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param array $input
     * @param int   $row
     * @param int   $column
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isDuplicate(array $input, int $row, int $column): bool
    {
        $candidate = $input[$row][$column];

        if (is_null($candidate)) {
            return false;
        }

        foreach (array_column($input, $column) as $r => $value) {
            if ($r !== $row && $value === $candidate) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $input
     * @param int   $row
     * @param int   $column
     * @param bool  $strict
     *
     * @return \Generator
     */
    private function swapCandidates(array &$input, int $row, int $column, bool $strict): \Generator
    {
        foreach ($input[$row] as $c => $dst) {
            if ((!$strict || !in_array($input[$row][$column], array_column($input, $c), true))
                && (is_null($dst) || !in_array($dst, array_column($input, $column), true))
            ) {
                yield $c;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param array $row
     * @param int   $from
     * @param int   $to
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function swap(array $row, int $from, int $to): array
    {
        $tmp = $row[$to];
        $row[$to] = $row[$from];
        $row[$from] = $tmp;

        return $row;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $input
     * @param int   $padSize
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function prepare(array $input, int $padSize): array
    {
        return array_map(function (array $row) use ($padSize): array {
            $row = array_pad($row, $padSize, null);
            shuffle($row);

            return $row;
        }, $input);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $input
     *
     * @return int
     */
    private function getMinRowLength(array $input): int
    {
        return max(
            ...array_values(array_count_values(array_merge(...$input))),
            ...array_map('count', $input)
        );
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<?php
$solver = new SwapSolver();
$solution = $solver->solve($input);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is solution i looking for, hope you enjoy it :)

Comment: @DorienCragen You're welcome! If you don't mind me asking, I'm curious, what will you be needing this for?

Comment: this will be part of speed dating matching places solution

Answer (score 7):

The soluton is quite simple actually. You check the number of unique chars and that's the number of values in the output array. Below code will do what you want almost instantly.

The hard part is removing the wildcards. This is something you can only do with bruteforce if you want 100% certainty. The solution below will try it's best to remove all wildcards by switching positions several times in order.

This is similar to the way google handles the [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp/tsp) in it's OR-tools. You need to find the best mix between accuracy and speed. By setting the loop count higher in the function below, chances of success increase. But it will be slower.

```
/* HELPERS */

function ShowNice($output) {
  //nice output:
  echo '<pre>';
  foreach($output as $key=>$val) {
    echo '<br />' . str_pad($key,2," ",STR_PAD_LEFT) . ' => [';
    $first = true;
    foreach($val as $char) {
      if (!$first) {
        echo ', ';
      }
      echo "'".$char."'";
      $first = false;
    }
    echo ']';
  }
  echo '</pre>';
}

function TestValid($output, $nullchar) {
  $keys = count($output[0]);
  for ($i=0;$i<$keys;$i++) {
    $found = [];
    foreach($output as $key=>$val) {
      $char = $val[$i];
      if ($char==$nullchar) {
        continue;
      }
      if (array_key_exists($char, $found)) {
        return false; //this char was found before
      }
      $found[$char] = true;
    }
  }

  return true;
}


$input = [
  0 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I', 'J'],
  1 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I'],
  2 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I'],
  3 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I'],
  4 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
  5 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
];

//generate large table
$genLength = 30; //max double alphabet
$innerLength = $genLength;
$input2 = [];
for($i=0;$i<$genLength;$i++) {
  $inner = [];

  if (rand(0, 1)==1) {
    $innerLength--;
  }

  for($c=0;$c<$innerLength;$c++) {
    $ascii = 65 + $c; //upper case
    if ($ascii>90) {
      $ascii += 6; //lower case
    }
    $inner[] = chr($ascii);
  }
  $input2[] = $inner;
}


//generate large table with different keys
$genLength = 10; //max double alphabet
$innerLength = $genLength;
$input3 = [];
for($i=0;$i<$genLength;$i++) {
  $inner = [];

  if (rand(0, 1)==1) {
    //comment o make same length inner arrays, but perhaps more distinct values
    //$innerLength--;
  }

  $nr = 0;
  for($c=0;$c<$innerLength;$c++) {
    $ascii = 65 + $c + $nr; //upper case
    if ($ascii>90) {
      $ascii += 6; //lower case
    }
    //$inner[] = chr($ascii);
    $inner[] = $c+$nr+1;

    //increase nr?
    if (rand(0, 2)==1) {
      $nr++;
    }

  }
  $input3[] = $inner;
}


//generate table with numeric values, to show what happens
$genLength = 10; //max double alphabet
$innerLength = $genLength;
$input4 = [];
for($i=0;$i<$genLength;$i++) {
  $inner = [];

  for($c=0;$c<$innerLength;$c++) {
    $inner[] = $c+1;
  }
  $input4[] = $inner;
}


$input5 = [
  0 => ['X', 'Y'],
  1 => ['X', 'Y'],
  2 => ['X', 'Y'],
];

$input6 = [
  0 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I', 'J'],
  1 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I'],
  2 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I'],
  3 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I'],
  4 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
];

$input7 = [
  ['X', 'Y', 'A', 'B'],
  ['X', 'Y', 'A', 'C']
];

$input8 = [
  ['X', 'Y', 'A'],
  ['X', 'Y', 'B'],
  ['X', 'Y', 'C']
];

$input9 = [
  ['X', 'Z', 'Y', 'A', 'E', 'D'],
  ['X', 'Z', 'Y', 'A', 'B'],
  ['X', 'Z', 'Y', 'A', 'C'],
  ['X', 'Z', 'Y', 'A', 'D'],
  ['X', 'Z', 'Y', 'A', 'D'],
  ['X', 'Z', 'Y', 'A', 'D']
];

/* ACTUAL CODE */

CreateOutput($input, 1);

function CreateOutput($input, $loops=0) {


  echo '<h2>Input</h2>';
  ShowNice($input);


  //find all distinct chars
  //find maxlength for any inner array

  $distinct = [];
  $maxLength = 0;
  $minLength = -1;
  $rowCount = count($input);
  $flipped = [];
  $i = 1;
  foreach($input as $key=>$val) {
    if ($maxLength<count($val)) {
      $maxLength = count($val);
    }
    if ($minLength>count($val) || $minLength==-1) {
      $minLength = count($val);
    }
    foreach($val as $char) {
      if (!array_key_exists($char, $distinct)) {
        $distinct[$char] = $i;
        $i++;
      }
    }

    $flipped[$key] = array_flip($val);
  }

  //keep track of the count for actual chars
  $actualChars = $i-1;
  $nullchar = '_';
  //add null values to distinct
  if ($minLength!=$maxLength && count($distinct)>$maxLength) {
    $char = '#'.$i.'#';
    $distinct[$nullchar] = $i; //now it only gets add when a key is smaller, not if all are the same size
    $i++;
  }

  //if $distinct count is small then rowcount, we need more distinct
  $addForRowcount = (count($distinct)<$rowCount);
  while (count($distinct)<$rowCount) {
    $char = '#'.$i.'#';
    $distinct[$char] = $i;
    $i++;
  }


  //flip the distinct array to make the index the keys
  $distinct = array_flip($distinct);

  $keys = count($distinct);

  //create output
  $output = [];
  $start = 0;
  foreach($input as $key=>$val) {
    $inner = [];
    for ($i=1;$i<=$keys;$i++) {
      $index = $start + $i;
      if ($index>$keys) {
          $index -= $keys;
      }

      if ($index>$actualChars) {
        //just add the null char
        $inner[] = $nullchar;
      } else {
        $char = $distinct[$index];

        //check if the inner contains the char
        if (!array_key_exists($char, $flipped[$key])) {
          $char = $nullchar;
        }

        $inner[] = $char;
      }

    }
    $output[] = $inner;
    $start++;
  }

  echo '<h2>First output, unchecked</h2>';
  ShowNice($output);

  $newOutput = $output;
  for ($x=0;$x<=$loops;$x++) {
    $newOutput = MoveLeft($newOutput, $nullchar);
    $newOutput = MoveLeft($newOutput, $nullchar, true);
    $newOutput = SwitchChar($newOutput, $nullchar);
  }

  echo '<h2>New output</h2>';
  ShowNice($newOutput);
  //in $newoutput we moved all the invalid wildcards to the end
  //now we need to test if the last row has wildcards

  if (count($newOutput[0])<count($output[0])) {
    $output = $newOutput;
  }


  echo '<h2>Best result ('.(TestValid($output, $nullchar)?'VALID':'INVALID').')</h2>';
  ShowNice($output);

  return $output;
}

function MoveLeft($newOutput, $nullchar, $reverse=false) {
  //see if we can remove more wildcards
  $lastkey = count($newOutput[0])-1;
  $testing = true;
  while ($testing) {
    $testing = false; //we decide if we go another round ob_deflatehandler
    $test = $newOutput;

    $lastkey = count($newOutput[0])-1;

    $start = 0;
    $end = count($test);
    if ($reverse) {
      $start = count($test)-1;
      $end = -1;
    }

    for($key = $start;$key!=$end;$key += ($reverse?-1:1) ) {
      $val = $test[$key];
      $org = array_values($val);
      foreach($val as $i=>$char) {
        if ($char!=$nullchar) {
          continue; //we only test wildcards
        }


        $wildcardAtEnd=true;
        for($x=$i+1;$x<=$lastkey;$x++) {
          $nextChar = $val[$x];
          if ($nextChar!=$nullchar) {
            $wildcardAtEnd = false;
            break;
          }
        }


        if ($wildcardAtEnd===true) {
          continue; //the char next to it must not be wildcard
        }

        //remove the wildcard and add it to the base64_encode
        unset($val[$i]);
        $val[] = $nullchar;
        $test[$key] = array_values($val); //correct order

        if (TestValid($test, $nullchar)) {
          //we can keep the new one
          $newOutput = $test;
          $testing = true; //keep testing, but start over to make sure we dont miss anything
          break 2; //break both foreach, not while
        }

        $test[$key] = $org; //reset original values before remove for next test
      }
    }
  }

  $allWildCards = true;
  while ($allWildCards) {
    $lastkey = count($newOutput[0])-1;
    foreach($newOutput as $key=>$val) {
      if ($val[$lastkey]!=$nullchar)  {
        $allWildCards = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if ($allWildCards) {
      foreach($newOutput as $key=>$val) {
        unset($val[$lastkey]);
        $newOutput[$key] = array_values($val);
      }
      $output = $newOutput;
    }
  }

  return $newOutput;
}

function SwitchChar($newOutput, $nullchar) {
  $switching = true;
  $switched = [];
  while($switching) {
    $switching = false;

    $test = $newOutput;
    $lastkey = count($newOutput[0])-1;

    foreach($test as $key=> $val) {
      foreach($val as $index=>$char) {
        $switched[$key][$index][$char] = true;//store the switches we make

        //see if can move the char somewhere else
        for($i=0;$i<=$lastkey;$i++)
        {
          if ($i==$index) {
            continue;//current pos
          }
          if (isset($switched[$key][$i][$char])) {
            continue; //been here before
          }

          $org = array_values($val);
          $switched[$key][$i][$char] = true;
          $t = $val[$i];
          $val[$index] = $t;
          $val[$i] = $char;
          $test[$key] = array_values($val);

          if (TestValid($test, $nullchar)) {
            //echo '<br />VALID: ' . $key . ' - ' . $index . ' - ' . $i . ' - ' . $t . ' - ' . $char;
            $newOutput = MoveLeft($test, $nullchar);
            $switching = true;
            break 3;//for and two foreach
          }

          //echo '<br />INVALID: ' . $key . ' - ' . $index . ' - ' . $i . ' - ' . $t . ' - ' . $char;
          $val = $org;
          $test[$key] = $org;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return $newOutput;
}
```

Result:

```
Input

   0 => ['X', 'Y', 'A']
   1 => ['X', 'Y', 'B']
   2 => ['X', 'Y', 'C']

   First output, unchecked

   0 => ['X', 'Y', 'A', '_', '_']
   1 => ['Y', '_', 'B', '_', 'X']
   2 => ['_', '_', 'C', 'X', 'Y']

   New output

   0 => ['X', 'Y', 'A', '_', '_']
   1 => ['Y', 'B', 'X', '_', '_']
   2 => ['C', 'X', 'Y', '_', '_']

   Best result (VALID)

   0 => ['X', 'Y', 'A']
   1 => ['Y', 'B', 'X']
   2 => ['C', 'X', 'Y']
```

Comment: You are right @Yoshi, but it has simple fix. Updated!

Comment: Appreciated, but on your $input array got `X` twice on key 0 in array 1 and 5

Comment: @DorienCragen: Ah yeh, i see. That's because of the update where I remove the diagonal line. I commented this part out and then it works again. I'll update this check in a second to solve that part to

Comment: sure is better now, but i found different error, for this array: `[
  0 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I', 'J'],
  1 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I'],
  2 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I'],
  3 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I'],
  4 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
]` array size is not comply with rule 8, `Solution should have as few wildcards as possible.`, got extra unnecessary wildcards across

Comment: @DorienCragen It's updated and checked with your test. It works

Comment: cool, it passes firsts tests, i'll double check it, but it looks good so far, no worries, I will put bounty again if this one ends

Comment: ok, i found issue :) whith array `[
  ['X', 'Y', 'A', 'B'],
  ['X', 'Y', 'A', 'C'], 
]` best solution may have no wildcards, but this should be easy to fix

Comment: @DorienCragen Updated again (and made it a function for easier testing). I removed the diagonal check and made a new check that tries to move wildcards to the end. If the last row contains only wildcards, remove it.

Comment: have tripple check this time :) and not working example: `[
  ['X', 'Y', 'A'],
  ['X', 'Y', 'B'],
  ['X', 'Y', 'C']
]` I'm sure output array can have size of 4

Comment: Fixed again. I changed the check for `nextchar==nullchar` to see if the wildcard is at the end of the row. Then I made a loop to remove more then one key from the end.Size of 3 now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159596/discussion-between-hugo-delsing-and-doriencragen).

Comment: This solution was most promising so far, but in `30x30` array and zero loops takes about 30s. to run, and to remove unnecessary wildcards, about 1000 iteration is needed, so again this is a *performance* issue :(

Comment: @DorienCragen i'm sure the code could be optimized a lot. I'm looping through arrays over and over and a lot of those things can be done better. Also the loops are now just random switches and movements, which does the same thing multiple times probably. There is no easy solution, although I thought there was. But with some effort the code could be smarter and thus faster, but unfortunately that takes more time then i'm willing to invest in a question, no matter how much fun the game is.

Answer (score 4):

what you should try to use is called a **Power set** which is:

> [from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) in mathematics, the power set (or powerset) of any set S is the set of
>   all subsets of S, including the empty set and S itself, variously
>   denoted as P(S), (S), ℘(S) (using the "Weierstrass p"), P(S), ℙ(S),
>   or, identifying the powerset of S with the set of all functions from S
>   to a given set of two elements, 2S.

if have a set of `{a,b,c}` it would give results of :

```
{{a,b,c},{a,b},{a,c},{b,c},{a},{b},{c}}
```

a useful php library from [github](https://github.com/ahungry/ahungry-powerset) will give the right results you are looking for in above rules if not all rules applied you can also try to add filters on the results to get them right.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answer to the previous question you supplied this can be solved ( in that case ) way more elegantly using a few built-in functions PHP has for array support.  Which is probably the best of any language.

```
function solve($matrix){
    $master = [];
    $_matrix = [];
    foreach($matrix as $key => $array){
        $_matrix[$key] = array_combine($array,$array);
        $master += $_matrix[$key];
    }
    $default = array_fill_keys($master, ''); 
    $result = [];
    foreach($_matrix as $array){
        $result[] = array_values(array_merge($default, $array));
    }
    print_r($result);
}
```

Using their same tests

```
$tests = [
    [ ['X'], ['X'] ],
    [ ['X'], ['X'], ['X'] ],
    [ [ 'X', '' ], [ '', 'X' ] ],
    [ ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['X', 'Y'], ['X']],
    [ ['X', 'Y'], ['X', 'Y'], ['X', 'Y'] ],
    [ ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z'] ],
    [ ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I', 'J'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z'] ],
];
array_map(function ($matrix) {
    solve($matrix);
}, $tests);
```

This is what I get in comparison

```
[
  0 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I', 'J'] //<- contains all unique values
  1 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I']
  2 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I']
  3 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I']
  4 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
  5 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
]
Their Result:
[
  0 => ['', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I', 'J'] //<- contains an extra '' empty value
  1 => ['', '', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I']
  2 => ['I', '', '', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
  3 => ['Z', 'I', '', '', 'X', 'Y']
  4 => ['Y', 'Z', '', '', '', 'X']
  5 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z', '', '', '']
]
My Result
[
  0 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I', 'J']
  1 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I', '']
  2 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I', '']
  3 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I', '']
  4 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z','','']
  5 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z','','']
]
```

You can test it here.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/86d0b4332963f95449df2e7d4d47fcd8224fe45d

I even timed it using microtime

mine `0.00013017654418945` milliseconds

theirs `0.10895299911499` milliseconds

Which is not really a surprise, as theirs is around 60 lines of code and 7 function calls. Mine is only 1 function 14 lines of code.

That said I don't know if the position of the values is important in the output.  Nor exactly what you expect as the output extending that question.

The fact is they also lose the index position, just look at the second array in their result, `2 => ['I', '', '', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']` compared to the input `2 => ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'I']`.  And I won't mention the extra `''` in the output that probably doesn't belong there.

Maybe I'm missing something, lol, I don't typically do these math-y type things.

**UPDATE** if you want an explanation of how this works,

- `array_combine($array,$array);` creates an array with matched key => value, we abuse the fact that array keys are unique by nature.  Like so `['X'=>'X','Y'=>'Y'...]`
- then we build a "master" array with all the values in it and matched keys, one array to rule them all. The master array is limited in size to the max number or unique values because we are using the keys to eliminate duplicates.
- then we use `array_fill_keys($master, '');` to sort of create a template of all the values.  The keys of "master" are all the unique values in all of the inner arrays, so we fill it with our "wildcard" placeholder.  In this case it looks like this `['X'=>'', 'Y'=>'', 'Z'=>'', 'I'=>'', 'J'=>'']`
- then we merge the "modified" original array, also abusing the array keys for our advantage, by replacing the placeholders in the "templated" master array with the "modified" original array, because the keys match.
- last we strip the keys from the array using `array_values`

And we are left with each inner array "templated" by the master array but with the original values filled in and the missing ones empty.

Comment: Your output doesnt comply with `Output inner array must have unique values on same key` . The first position has all the `X`, the second the `Y`, etc. The goal is to get only one `X` on the first position and one `Y` on the second, etc.

Answer (score 1):

hope this is the **solution** we looking for, I have **request** for everybody to **check my solution**

the code:

```
<?php
$input = [
    [ 'F', 'I', 'J', 'Z' ],
    [ 'F', 'R', 'U', 'V' ],
    [ 'I', 'R', 'U', 'V' ],
    [ 'M', 'P', 'U', 'V' ],
];
do {
    $result = calculate($input);
} while(!TestValid($input, $result, '_'));


echo (TestValid($input, $result, '_')) ? 'VALID' : 'INVALID';

ShowNice($result);

function TestValid($input, $output, $nullchar) {

    foreach($output as $k => $o) {
        $test = array_filter($o, function($v) use ($nullchar) {
            return $v != $nullchar;
        });

        if (count($test) != count($input[$k])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function ShowNice($output) {
    $height = getHeight($output);

  foreach($output as $k => $v ) {
        for($i = 0;$i < $height;$i ++) {

            if (!isset($output[$k][$i])) {
                $output[$k][$i] = '_';
            }
        }
    }

  echo '<pre>';
  foreach($output as $key=>$val) {
    echo '<br />' . str_pad($key,2," ",STR_PAD_LEFT) . ' => [';
    ksort($val);
    echo join(', ', $val);
    echo ']';
  }
  echo '</pre>';
}

function calculate($array) {

    echo "<pre>";
    $full = getFullList($array);

    foreach($full as $f) {
        $frequency[$f] = getFrequency($array, $f);
    }

    // uksort($frequency, function($i, $j) use ($frequency) { 
    //     return $frequency[$j] <=> $frequency[$i];
    // });

    $frequency = array_keys($frequency);

    shuffle($frequency);


    $height = getHeight($array);

    foreach($array as $k => $v ) {
        for($i = 0;$i < $height;$i ++) {
            if (!isset($array[$k][$i]))
                $array[$k][$i] = '_';
        }
    }

    foreach($array as $key => $value ) {
        $output[$key] = [];
        $used[$key] = [];
    }

    foreach($array as $key => $value ) {
        foreach($frequency as $k => $v) {

            $j = 0;

            foreach($array as $kk => $col) {
                if (in_array($v, $col)) {
                    for ($h = 0; $h <= $height; $h++) {

                        if (!isset($_h[$v][$kk])) {
                            $_h[$v][$kk] = 0;
                        }

                        if ($h + $_h[$v][$kk] >= $height) {
                            $hh = ($h + $_h[$v][$kk]) - $height;
                        } else {
                            $hh = $h + $_h[$v][$kk];
                        }
                        $row = getRow($output, $hh);
                        if (!in_array($v, $row) && !in_array($v, $used[$kk])) {
                            if (!isset($output[$kk][$hh]) || $output[$kk][$hh] == '_') {
                                $output[$kk][$hh] = $v;
                                $used[$kk][] = $v;

                                $keys = array_keys($array);
                                foreach($keys as $i => $ke) {
                                    if ($ke == $kk) {
                                        if(isset($keys[$i+1])) {
                                            $_h[$v][$keys[$i + 1]] = $hh;
                                        } else {
                                            $_h[$v][$keys[0]] = $hh;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                               $unused[$kk] = array_diff($col, $used[$kk]);
                                $j++;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // ShowNice($output);
        }

    }
    foreach($output as $k => $v ) {
        for($i = 0;$i < $height;$i ++) {
            if (!isset($output[$k][$i]))
                $output[$k][$i] = '_';
        }
    }

    foreach($output as $k => $o) {
        ksort($output[$k]);
    }

    return $output;
}

function getHeight($array) {
    $heights = [];
    $max3 = count($array);
    $max2 = 0;
    foreach($array as $v) {
        if ($max2 < count($v)) {
            $max2 = count($v);
        }

        foreach ($v as $e) {
            $heights[$e] = (isset($heights[$e])) ? $heights[$e] + 1 : 1;
        }

    }
    $max = 0;
    foreach ($heights as $h ) {
        if ($h > $max) {
            $max = $h;
        }
    }

    return max($max, $max2, $max3);
}

function getRow($array, $row) {
    $res = [];
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        if (is_array($a)) {
            foreach($a as $k =>$b) {
                if ($row == $k) {
                    $res[] = $b;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $res;
}

function getFrequency($array, $value) {
    $c=0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $v) {
        foreach ($v as $e) {
            if ($e == $value) 
                $c++;
        }
    }
    return $c;
}

function getFullList($array) {

    $m = [];
    foreach($array as $a) {
        $m = array_merge($m, $a);
    }

    return array_unique($m);
}
```

**UPDATED**

This may be the final, check please: **playground**: https://eval.in/906355

Comment: @Yoshi thats good one, thanks, have no idea how to fix it now, but I see the point

Comment: With my tests it seems to fail for all cases where the input has more rows than columns, e.g.: [`AY, LN, OS`](https://eval.in/906334) but this seems like a minor error.

Comment: @Yoshi what if wildcard on the end can be ignored? looks fine

Comment: @Yoshi I have fixed this as well, is not final, but should work for your 4x4 :)

Comment: It looks very promising, though for 9x9 this takes around 10-30 seconds on my machine, and hasn't finished for 10x10 yet.